# PDF previewer with latextools / sublime in Linux?

Tags: pdf, linux, sublime-text

I use Ubuntu and Sublime2.

I was reading through the latextools readme, and got .tex files to compile and produce a PDF file with latextools in sublime. However, I thought that the PDF was supposed to be displayed via a PDF viewer on compile? Can anyone help me get this option to work? It would be very, very nice.

Sorry if I seem a bit naive or noobie!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Just to check the most obvious thing: you do have Evince installed on your system right? Currently, LaTeXTools only supports displaying PDFs via Evince.